# Android ListView being replaced by a drawable or showing incorrect background

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, drawable

I am seeing some very weird behavior with a set of ListViews that I have in a single Activity.

I have 5 ListViews that make up a custom control that acts like a lock combination on a briefcase.  All 5 of these have transparent backgrounds and they are overlaid on top of their background using a RelativeLayout.

Every once and a while, all 5 of the ListView backgrounds will be filled with a drawable png image that I have on the same Activity.  When this image shows up, there are no elements in the ListViews like their should be.  I usually clean the project and push it back onto the phone which fixes the problem. However, I am trying to figure out if the issue will happen whether or not it worked out of the box.

I am not sure if the ListView is being entirely replaced by the drawable.  I DO know that there are never any elements in the ListViews when the issue occurs.

What would cause the issue of an image resource showing up as the ListView, instead of the ListView and their contents?

**Update:**
I thought this could be resolved by cleaning/rebuilding the project, however I'm now finding out that this problem occurs during run-time.

After replace an image on the home screen, I found that the image being incorrectly loaded into the ListView is actually from another Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I used my own transparent `#00000000` color for the `android:divider` of the `ListView`, I would see this issue.

The fix was to use `@android:color/transparent` instead, and the behavior corrected itself.

Comment: I really don't know why but it helped. I've got the similar problem but instead of ListView the background of TextView was wrong. I also used 'transparent' background with custom color (not android:color/transparent). Setting it to android:color/transparent solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is the background of a parent element in your layout XML, then it will show up when your lists are empty.

Comment: The image is actually the src of an ImageView, which leads me to believe there is some wierd caching issue going on.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, does your ListView specify an empty image to be displayed when there are no elements in the list?

Comment: The ListView should always have a transparent background.

Comment: Yes, but if you put an ImageView and a ListView in a FrameLayout, or in a RelativeLayout without specifying which view is relative to which other view, you can get this behavior. Do your ListView items have backgrounds?

Comment: No, the image/lists are not overlapping each other.  The `ImageView` becomes stretched/distorted to fill the width/height of the `ListView`